# How do you configure debug builds to point to different apis?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have two base urls for my api, one for prod & one for debug. I was wondering if there was a way I can use Android Studio's Gradle build types to grab the right api.

So basically, I want to move away from

```
String url;
if(isDebug){
   url = getDebugApiURL();
}
else{
    url = getReleaseApiURL();
```

to just have the app return the right api url. Is there a way I can do this? If so how should I go about configuring it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `buildConfigField` method inside your `buildTypes`.

For example:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
             buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"api.example.com\""
        }

        debug {
             buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"debug-api.example.com\""
        }
    }
}
```

You then use this field in your code via `BuildConfig.API_URL`. The build tools plugin already define a number of `BuildConfig` fields for you, such as `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, and with Gradle you can add your own to the mix!

Documentation [is located here](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:buildConfigField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: And you can use that via: BuildConfig. API_URL

Comment: Oops, thought I had mentioned that. Thanks!